# Django upload image to cdn using an API

Tags: python, django, file-upload, cdn

I am building a website in Django on Pythonanywhere.com and I am using Backblaze's B2 cloud storage to store all the static and media files. My css and images that I have uploaded to Backblaze are working but I can't figure out how everything should fit together, so here is where I am (minimalized):

In this model I want to store a thumbnail image, I have a form working to upload it.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    (...)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, width_field="width_field", height_field="height_field")
    (...)
```

Backblaze has all the code for the http requests and responses that I need, so I just pasted that in a seperate file. I first need to get an account authorization token, followed by an upload url and then I can send the file.

So that whole function needs three things as input: the file date, file name and file size. As output I get the file id (and other things, details [here](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/b2_upload_file.html)).

Now I wonder where I need to call that upload function, I assume it has to do with the "upload_to" parameter in the ImageField. And I wonder what actually gets stored in the ImageField, since I don't tell ImageField the location where to find the file. Does it use the media root in the settings file, how would I manage this?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to store the images on disk on PythonAnywhere but instead want to store it at backblaze? Are the images something that your users submit? Or do you have preuploaded images that you just want to display now?

Comment: Correct, I want to use Backblaze as the CDN. I have preuploaded pictures and css/JavaScript files, I got those working. Now I indeed want to get users to upload images and have those stored there.

Comment: Check out django-storages. It has support for most storage backends (but not backblaze). It seems like you just need to implement read/write/close/size methods for the backend and you are good to go. You can even submit a pull request to get them to merge it upstream!

Answer (score 0):

Using these commands in settings, You can set MEDIA_URL as well as where image is to be stored. Here image is stored in src/media_cdn

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media_cdn")
```

You have to tell the path where upload_to should save the image inside media_cdn else it will save image inside media_cdn, if upload_to is set to None.

```
models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles/')
```

You need to upload image. So, that it contains address where image exist.

Comment: But I believe that I can't just let Django save the image to the filepath of Backblaze. I need to use the API for that right?

Comment: I think you have your workspace there and you can do anything inside it as heroku, amazon, azure etc do. Still if you are unable to do so and have github repository. I would like to help you.

Comment: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-digitalocean-spaces/